# Obtaining information from Mongo DB Cursor

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using Mongo DB With Java .

I am trying to find out if there exists a Symbol with the given String in the Mongo DB as  shown below 
This is working , but the problem is that it is making two calls to the MOngo DB , which is very expensive .
Is there any way i can reduce it to one call and make it more performance oriented .

This is my code

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        DBCursor cursor  = null;
        DBCollection coll = null;
        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
        String symbol = args[0];
        query.put("symbol", "" + symbol);
        cursor  = coll.find(query);
        int count = coll.find(query).count();

        /* Here is want to avoid the count call , is there anyway by which
           the cursor the obtained cursor tells , that there exists the symbol
           in Mongo DB */

        if(count>=1)
        {
            // If found then do 
            if (cursor != null) {

            }
        }
        else
        {
            // If Not  found then do 
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using `count` at all? You can just use the `hasNext()` method of `DBCursor` to test whether something is fetched or not.

```
cursor  = coll.find(query);

if (cursor.hasNext()) {
    // Found
    System.out.println(cursor.next());
} else {
    // Not found
}
```

---

However, if you want to use `count()` method, then also you don't have to fire a new query. Since `db.collection.find()` returns a `DBCursor` only. So, the `count` method you are using is on the returned `DBCursor`. So, just invoke `count()` on the same `cursor` reference: -

```
cursor  = coll.find(query);
int count = cursor.count();

if (count >= 1) {
    // Found
    System.out.println(cursor.next());
} else {
    // Not found
}
```

But, you should use the first approach, if you want to fetch the next element if present.

Comment: Thanks Rohit , so you mean to say that cursor.count(); will not make another DataBase Call ?? Am i right ??

Comment: @PreethiJain.. Yes you are right. It will not make another call. Cursor is just like ResultSet in JDBC. You can access each record by moving the cursor ahead, thus exhausting the entire result that was returned from the query.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to make an explicit call to get the count.

`cursor.hasNext()` will return whether there is any element in the cursor or not.

```
    cursor  = coll.find(query);
    while(cursor.hasNext()){
     // found
    }else{
     // not found
    }
```

You can also use     `cursor.count()`

```
The count() method counts the number of documents referenced by a cursor.
```

Append the `count()` method to a find() query to return the number of matching documents, as in the following prototype:

```
db.collection.find().count()
   or 
db.collection.count()
```

This operation does not actually perform the `find();` instead, the operation counts the results that would be returned by the `find()`.

[Reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/)